# Java mail with domain smtp?

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send email via my domain email. I tried with 2 different ports 465 and 587. However, in both forms this exception occurs.

When I run this code with google smtp 465 port, it works perfectly. But because of daily limit of google, I need to send email via domain email address.

Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
public static void sendMailTo() throws Exception {

    String mailAddress = "mail@mydomain.com";
    String mailPassword = "password";

    String messageContext = "Content";

    try {

        String to = "ahmet****@gmail.com";

        Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());
        final String SSL_FACTORY = "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory";

        // Get a Properties object
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.setProperty("mail.smtps.host", "smtp.mydomain.com");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", SSL_FACTORY);
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "587");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtps.auth", "true");

        props.put("mail.smtps.quitwait", "false");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);

        // -- Create a new message --
        final MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

        // -- Set the FROM and TO fields --
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(mailAddress));
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(to, false));

        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();

        msg.setSubject("Yeni Kullanici! (" + dateFormat.format(date) + ")");
        msg.setText(messageContext, "utf-8");
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());

        SMTPTransport t = (SMTPTransport) session.getTransport("smtps");

        t.connect("smtp.mydomain.com", mailAddress, mailPassword);
        t.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
        t.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Exception :

```
com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.mydomain.com, 587; timeout -1;

  nested exception is:
    java.net.UnknownHostException: smtp.mydomain.com
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2100)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:699)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:345)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:226)
    at verego.MailSender.sendMailToTeacher(MailSender.java:86)
    at verego.MailSender.main(MailSender.java:37)

Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: smtp.mydomain.com
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:331)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:217)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2066)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: You should ask your provider or system administrators what mail server you can use. As the error indicates, there is no mailserver `smtp.mydomain.com`.

Comment: No, the error indicates that the host is unable to resolve the smtp.mydomain.com hostname. You should ask an admin to register this hostname your used DNS server. If you know the IP address to the hostname, you can put it to your hostfile for a while (keeping it in your mind that when the IP behind this hostname will be changed, you have to update your hostfile)